# argparse library: PythonShell.py: error: unrecognized arguments

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, databricks

I have this code below in the notebook called "sample" in databricks

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--arg1')
parser.add_argument('--arg2')

arguments = parser.parse_args()

print(arguments)
```

And I try to run the "sample" notebook from a different notebook like this

```
%run ./sample $arg1="some_text" $arg2="some_text"
```

I get the following error:

```
usage: PythonShell.py [-h] [--arg1 ARG1] [--arg2 ARG2]
PythonShell.py: error: unrecognized arguments: 35415 0 50000 1000 620e09fb254e45a38e2499618d76c4b8 3.0.1 f580cca74ed613c678816aa76dd5a75912dbd0bb81fe8bb5d2e7a7434ff5998a unpinned
The execution of this command did not finish successfully
Command took 0.16 seconds -- by 7/12/2021, 7:40:13 PM
usage: PythonShell.py [-h] [--arg1 ARG1] [--arg2 ARG2]
PythonShell.py: error: unrecognized arguments: 35415 0 50000 1000 620e09fb254e45a38e2499618d76c4b8 3.0.1 f580cca74ed613c678816aa76dd5a75912dbd0bb81fe8bb5d2e7a7434ff5998a unpinned
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `argparse.ArgumentParser`, then it will retrieve the arguments of the Python interpreter that is attached to your notebook, but not the parameters that you passed to your `sample` notebook.

If you want to retrieve parameters passed to `%run` or [dbutils.notebook.run function](https://docs.databricks.com/notebooks/notebook-workflows.html#api), then you need to use [the dbutils.widgets.get function](https://docs.databricks.com/notebooks/widgets.html) that receives one argument - parameter name.  For example, if you put this into your `sample` notebook:

```py
print("arg1=", dbutils.widgets.get("arg1"))
print("arg2=", dbutils.widgets.get("arg2"))
```

you'll see as result:

```
arg1= some_text1
arg2= some_text2
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use this
`%run ./sample --arg1="some_text" --arg2="some_text"`